# Restler Won't recognize more than one class

Tags: php, api, rest, restler

I want to create a API to access information about library patrons and books in the MySQL database we use
It is based of the CRUD example with everything but GET removed
So I have 4 files:
`db_pdo_mysql.php` which holds the functions
`index.php` calls the classes
`book.php` holds the book class
`patron.php` holds the patron class


In the index.php file I call the classes as so:

```
    require_once '../../restler/restler.php';
    spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload');

    $r = new Restler();
    $r->addAPIClass('book');
    $r->addAPIClass('patron');
    $r->handle();
```

Book.php:

```
    <?php
   class book {
public $dp;



function __construct(){
    /**
    * $this->dp = new DB_PDO_Sqlite();
    * $this->dp = new DB_PDO_MySQL();
    * $this->dp = new DB_Serialized_File();
    */
    $this->dp = new DB_PDO_MySQL();
}





function get($id=NULL) {
    return is_null($id) ? $this->dp->getAll() : $this->dp->book($id);
}




}
    }
     ?>
```

patron.php:

```
    <?php
    class patron {
public $dp;



function __construct(){
    /**
    * $this->dp = new DB_PDO_Sqlite();
    * $this->dp = new DB_PDO_MySQL();
    * $this->dp = new DB_Serialized_File();
    */
    $this->dp = new DB_PDO_MySQL();
}



function get($id=NULL) {
    return is_null($id) ? $this->dp->getAll() : $this->dp->patron($id);
}



    }
    ?>
```

and db_pdo_mysql.php

```
    <?php


    class DB_PDO_MySQL
    {
        private $db;
        function __construct ()
        {
            try {
    //update the dbname username and password to suit your server
        $this->db = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=[HOST REMOVED];dbname=[DATABASE REMOVED]', '[USERNAME REMOVED]',                    '[PASSWORD REMOVED]');
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, 
        PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new RestException(501, 'MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}


function patron ($id)
{
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM patrons WHERE code = ' . mysql_escape_string(
        $id);
        return $this->id2int($this->db->query($sql)
            ->fetch());
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        throw new RestException(501, 'MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

 function book ($id)
{
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM books WHERE barcode = ' . mysql_escape_string(
        $id);
        return $this->id2intBooks($this->db->query($sql)
            ->fetch());
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        throw new RestException(501, 'MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
function getAll ()
{
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM patrons');
        return $this->id2int($stmt->fetchAll());
    } catch (PDOException $e) {

        throw new RestException(501, 'MySQL: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

private function id2int ($r)
{
    if (is_array($r)) {
        if (isset($r['code'])) {
            $r['code'] = intval($r['code']);

        } else {

            foreach ($r as $a) {
                $a['code'] = intval($a['code']);
            }
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
private function id2intBooks ($r)
{
    if (is_array($r)) {
        if (isset($r['barcode'])) {
            $r['barcode'] = intval($r['barcode']);

        } else {

            foreach ($r as $a) {
                $a['barcode'] = intval($a['barcode']);
            }
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

   }
    ?>
```

I use `[domain]/api/test/index.php/patron/[patron id]` and `[domain]/api/test/index.php/book/[book id]` to access data.

I am very confused!

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in the index.php, I didn't call the patron class correctly!